# Repeatable File Store Stream for Mule 4.3 Community Edition

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

I am using `repeatable-in-memory-stream` in Mule 4 Community Edition.

```
<repeatable-in-memory-stream initialBufferSize="1" bufferSizeIncrement="5" maxBufferSize="100" bufferUnit="MB" />
```

But recently we started receiving very large files and the `file:listener` is failing with the following error:

> org.mule.runtime.core.internal.streaming.bytes.MaxStreamingMemoryExceededException:
> Max streaming memory limit of 2000000000 bytes was exceeded

Can Repeatable File Store Stream be used to read large files. Is there any possibility to use Repeatable File Store Stream with the `file:listener` in Mule 4 Community Edition?

Answer (score 0):

As you can read in the documentation for repeatable streaming, the [File-Stored Repeatable Stream](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/4.3/streaming-about#file-stored-repeatable-stream) configuration is available only in the Enterprise Edition:

> File storage is only available in Mule Enterprise Edition (Mule EE).

Comment: Thanks. Is there any other way to configure the file listener or the Mule Runtime to make the application able to read large files. I mean in my case the file size I am trying to read with the File listener is 125 MB and I have configured runtime with -M-Dmule.max.streaming.memory=2000000000 which is around 2 GB. But still I am getting MaxStreamingMemoryExceededException.

Comment: You didn't provide enough details of the error to understand if the issue is in the listener or some other component. If the file is 125 MB it should not cause the error, unless the file listener is receiving several of them or they are processed into a format that requires more memory than the file content. Are you using the last version of the connector?